# How to return the value of query from function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, function

I have crated one function to return the result of executed SQL query as follows:

```
EDITED :

 public int GetChips(int points, string username)
    {
        int chip = 0;
        string getChips = "SELECT  Chips from tbl_UserInfo where UserName =' " + username + " '";
        con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getChips, con);
        MySqlDataReader chips = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (chips.Read())
        {
            chip = chips.GetInt32(0);
            if (chip > points)
            {
                if (points == 5000)
                {
                    chip = chip - 5000;
                }
                else if (points == 10000)
                {
                    chip = chip - 10000;
                }
            }


        }
        con.Close();

        return chip;
    }
```

It returns chip's value as 0. This code does not go in 'while' condition.

What can be the problem ?

How can I solve this ?

Comment: what is chips? shouldnt it be temp? and temp[]...

Comment: You are just returning the last value of `chip`, subtracted by 5000 or 10000 if the last value of `chip` was greater than `points`. Not sure what you mean by "the outer most chip's value".

Comment: What result are you getting and what result did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to your edited question:

Are you sure the select statement is returning any values at all? You have a space inside your `' "` and `" '"` so it will look for `' Rohan '` in stead of `'Rohan'`. Try

```
UserName ='" + username + "'"
```

Or better yet, like Jon suggested, use parameterized queries!

Comment: @comecme- thanks for reply. Ya my select query returns value.But It doesnt go inside While conditionand returns 0 : (

Comment: ya you were right. That was the problem. Now it works fine. Thanks. : )

Answer (score 3):

Well yes... `temp` is a `MySqlDataReader`, not an `int`. You can't assign a `MySqlDataReader` to a variable of type `int`.

I suspect you want:

```
chip = temp.GetInt32(0);
```

Note that you should use `using` statements to release all your resources, rather than just closing the connection explicitly. You should also consider what you want to happen if there's more than one result (or no results).

Additionally, your code will fail at execution time at the moment unless the user puts their username in quotes. *Don't* fix this by adding quotes to the SQL - use parameterized queries instead. Otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Basically, you should pretty much never build SQL dynamically using values like this - always parameterize them instead.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have used your code and it works fine. But it doesnt return exact value i want. Please validate my edited code and help me to solve it.

Comment: @Rohan: No, you've completely ignored the gaping security hole I warned you about. It sounds like you're not matching the username, if it's not getting into the `while` loop...

Comment: @Jon, exactly. The query is now looking for something like `UserName = ' Rohan '` in stead of `'Rohan'`.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a `MySqlDataReader` whereas `chip` is an `int`. Of course your can't assign one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Because your query just returns a value, so you can use this:

```
chip  = (int)(command.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0);
```

Have a look at following link for more detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx